# Android Studio not resolving Django directories

Tags: python, android

the url loads successfully the page but it throws Django Attribute error.
This happens only when I attempt from android studio on google pixel phone.

If I use a browser instead the app runs fine.

Note : Only receives error from Android studio. On web browser the website operates just fine. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQGq.jpg)

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings Websettings = web.getSettings();
        Websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        //web.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        web.loadUrl("http://72.195.XXX27:8X60/friclXXp/index");

Comment: 72.195.XXX27:8X60/friclXXp/index - Website works fine directly on browser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.